# Using velocity to move rectangle in javascript using processing.js

Tags: javascript, html, physics, processing, processing.js

I am working on a simple pong clone using javascript and processing.js . I have made classes for the paddles, which are then extended to make a class which will be controlled by the player(s). Currently, I am attempting to implement handling for keyboard input within the player controlled class. My intent is that when `w` or `s` is pressed, I update the position of the player's paddle through a velocity represented by a `pVector` variable within the player class.

However, when the corresponding keys are pressed, currently the paddle simply disappears.

The script can be seen on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ma6rt/9/), and My code is as follows:

```
  // For reference
  // standard rectangle constructor is: rect(x, y, width, height);

    class Paddle
    {
        //width of paddle
        float pWidth;
        //height of paddle
        float pHeight;
        //initial paddle x coordinate
        float x;
        //initial paddle y coordinate
        float y;

        Paddle(float w, float h, float startX, float startY)
        {
            //set width
            paddleWidth = w;
            //set height
            paddleHeight = h;
            //set start x
            x = startX;
            //set start y
            y = startY;
        }

        void update()
        {
        }

        void draw()
        {
            //draw and fill rectangle with white
            fill(255)
            rect(x,y,paddleWidth,paddleHeight)
        }
    }

    class Player extends Paddle
    {
        Player(float w, float h, float startX, float startY)
        {
            super(w,h,startX,startY);
        }
    }

    class PlayerOne extends Paddle
    {
        pVector playerVelocity = (0,0);

        PlayerOne(float w, float h, float startX, float startY)
        {
            super(w,h,startX,startY);
        }

        void update()
        {
            debugger;

            if(keyPressed)
            {
                if(key == 'w')
                {
                    y -= playerVelocity.y;
                }
                else if(key == 's')
                {
                    y += playerVelocity.y;
                }
            }    
        }
    }


    //array list to hold the player paddles
    ArrayList<Paddle> paddles = new ArrayList<Paddle>();
    //middle x and middle y
    float mx, my, pw, ph;

    void setup()
    {
        mx = width/2;
        my = height/2;
        pw = 10;
        ph = 50;

        player1 = new PlayerOne(pw,ph,10,10);
        player2 = new Player(pw,ph,385,10);

        paddles.add(player1);
        paddles.add(player2);

        size(400,400);
    }

    void draw()
    {
        background(0);
        fill(100,100,0);

        // update each paddle added to array list
        for(Paddle p: paddles)
        {
            p.update();
            p.draw();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I put a breakpoint in with the line `debugger` after the condition on key press: `if(keyPressed)` . It seems that if the key is pressed once, it is detected repeatedly on every update for some reason.

Comment: have you tried using a javascript debugger? e.g. Firebug addin for Firefox. Really useful for figuring out problems like this. At a quick glance you don't seem to handle things going out of bounds...

Comment: I have really been doing the whole thing through jsfiddle. Would a browser js debugger allow debugging of code run through jsfiddle? My assumption is yes, since I assume a script is just run through the site, so forgive my ignorance if that is a stupid question.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to put a breakpoint in with the line `debugger` after the condition on key press: `if(keyPressed)` . It seems that if the key is pressed once, it is detected repeatedly on every update for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Procesing IDE it won't even compile... it should be PVector instead of pVector, but in jsfiddle it compiles... Also you need to use `new` with PVectors. So  playerVelocity in not correctly initialized and when added to position goes nuts... Try:

```
PVector playerVelocity = new PVector(1,1);
```

note that if velocity is 0 there will be no move, so I used 1.
hth

Comment: Making that change fixed the issue. Thank you for the help. May I ask what processing.js IDE you use/recommend?

Comment: My pleasure. Actually I was talking about the Processing IDE. You can download it @ http://processing.org. There is not a real debug tool (there is a beta debug mode in 2.0.x, but i never tried it) but there are some helpful messages in the console. It's a Processing/java environment, not javaScript.